# if statement around javascript/html data option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append results in an object as options in a datalist dropdown, and it works but the problem is not all elements have a certain level in the object always which affects what results get appended to the list.

```
$("#returnedProducts").append($("<option/>",
                {
                    "srindex": i,
                    "data-details": JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.name.family),
                    //I want to say if result[i]._source.fabric exists, then do this next line else, just move to "value"
                    "data-fabric":JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.fabric[1]),
                    "value": result[i]._source.category,
                    "html": result[i]._source.category,
                }
        ));
```

How can I make this say "Only set data-fabric if result[i]._source.fabric exists,else don't set it and move to "value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do something like that inside an object initializer, but you can easily do it if you assemble your options object in a function:

```
$("#returnedProducts").append($("<option/>", function() {
        var object = {
                "srindex": i,
                "data-details": JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.name.family),
                "value": result[i]._source.category,
                "html": result[i]._source.category,
            };
         if (result[i]._source.fabric) {
            object["data-fabric"] = JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.fabric[1]);
         }
         return object;
    )() ); // note that the function is called here
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operator:

```
{
    "srindex": i,
    "data-details": JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.name.family),
    "data-fabric": result[i]._source.fabric ? JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.fabric[1]) : undefined,
    "value": result[i]._source.category,
    "html": result[i]._source.category,
}
```

Let me know if this needs more clarification

Comment: This works, but it *always* adds a `data_fabric` property, which *might* matter but probably not.

Comment: @Pointy, very true the object will still display the property, the value will just be `undefined`

Comment: Thanks @Peter Van Drunen :)